# json file in libgdx

Tags: json, parsing, libgdx

I try to add json skin file in my libgdx project but I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: gfx/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: gfx/uiskin.json
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: gfx/uiskin.json
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Field not found: font      (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle)
```

My code:

```
public void create() {
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    ui = new Stage();
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/uiskin.json"));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(ui);
    label = new Label("fps", skin);
    label.setText("fps:"+Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());
    window = new Window("alarm", skin);
    window.setPosition(10, 10);
    ui.addActor(window);
}


public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ui.draw();
}
```

json

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
            medium: { file: abc.fnt }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: medium }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { font: medium }
}
}
```

I have in asset/gfx folder: abc.fnt, abc.png, uiskin.json 
I don’t know what am I doing wrong? I searched about it but found nothing. Thanks for help.

Comment: I've tried to use the skin json function, but it was too buggy for me. so I've ended up building the skin programmatically since it is almost the same because you are already using java class and methods names in the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `font` field for `Window$WindowStyle` ([WindowStyle Javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Window.WindowStyle.html))

The available fields are:

- background
- titleFont
- titleFontColor
- stageBackground

---

You should be doing something similar to this.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome. LibGDX is great once you get used to the way everything works!